# pip install selenium permission error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, selenium3

I am trying to install selenium 3 on mac using default python i.e. `/usr/bin/python`
But when I try to install it https://pypi.org/project/selenium/ using

`pip install selenium` I get error
Collecting selenium
  Using cached

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/c6/78a9a0d0150dbf43095c6f422fdf6f948e18453c5ebbf92384175b372ca2/selenium-3.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: selenium
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

If i install using `--user` as `pip install --user selenium` it works but when I run test with code

```
driver = webdriver.Safari(executable_path="/Users/Desktop/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar")
```

I get error

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

Why I'm getting error and is there a way to install without `--user` and `sudo` because even with these options it doesn't work.

Comment: Sudo is Linux. Also, why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solved the first problem by using `--user` - the second problem is a different issue.

this line `webdriver.Safari(executable_path=...)` is pointing to the wrong path - you should point it to wherever the `savaridriver` executable that comes with safari 10 and not to a `.jar` file.

Something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/safaridriver')
```

Just check the path in your mac and find out where your `safaridriver` is.